# Finding a path in Rails folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I wanted for debuging purpsoes learn how to use Logging, previously I used to write `"puts"` every where and see them in console.
But will logging I need something as simple as `Rails.logger.debug('Hello from this place')`

I found that looks like logging goes somewhere like this:

```
#{Rails.root}/log/#{Rails.env}.log
```

But still having problem navigating to such a path :)

Ok if I do a which rails thats what I get:

```
/Users/EricCartman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/rails
```

so now how should I navigate to get there? I am in Dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs are found in the `log` directory of your rails application.

So where you would enter `rails s` to start your application, try `ls -l log` to list the log files.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to print some value it more easier to just print it

```
 p some_variable
```

if will be printed in your running server log

or in your view you can use

```
 <%= debug some_variable %>
```